# NASM - Load code from USB Drive

Tags: nasm, bootloader, usb-drive, qemu

Would any assembly gurus know the argument (register *dl*) that signifies the first USB drive?

I'm working through a couple of NASM tutorials, and would like to get a physical boot (I can get a clean one with qemu).

This is the section of code that loads the "kernel" data from disk:

```
loadkernel:
    mov si, LMSG ;; 'Loading kernel',13,10,0
    call prints  ;; ex puts()

    mov dl, 0x00 ;; The disk to load from
    mov ah, 0x02 ;; Read operation
    mov al, 0x01 ;; Sectors to read
    mov ch, 0x00 ;; Track
    mov cl, 0x02 ;; Sector
    mov dh, 0x00 ;; Head
    mov bx, 0x2000 ;; Buffer end
    mov es, bx
    mov bx, 0x0000 ;; Buffer start

    int 0x13
    jc loadkernel

    mov ax, 0x2000
    mov ds, ax

    jmp 0x2000:0x00
```

If it makes any difference, I'm running a stock Dell Inspiron 15 BIOS.

---

Apparently, the correct value for me is 0x80.

The BIOS loads the hard drives and labels them starting at 0x80 [according to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/548492/how-to-perform-low-level-io-with-a-usb-flash-drive-under-the-bios-compared-to-a/4248266#4248266).

My particular BIOS decides to load the USB drive up as the first, for some reason, so I can boot from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple answer is that the correct value for `dl` is in `dl`.

> 

The happy answer is that the `dl` value with `int 13h, ah=8` GET DRIVE PARAMETERS returns the geometry to use and allows the FAT12 floppy disk image code to run from any BIOS/version that can boot from a USB flash drive.

See my post here: [USB Booting Secrets](http://board.flatassembler.net/topic.php?p=124387)